# Connecting to Oracle DB from shell script with 'sysdba'

Tags: shell, oracle11g

I need to connect my Oracle 11g DB from shell script with 'sysdba' permissions. To do this I have to switch user from 'root' to 'oracle'.
I've tried the following with no success.

```
su - oracle -c "<< EOF1
    sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" << EOF2
    whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
    set echo off 
    set heading off

    shutdown immediate
    startup mount
    alter database archivelog;
    alter database open;

    exit;
    EOF2
EOF1"
```

I'm getting the following error.

> [root@vEMS-23 devel]# ./enableArchiveLogs.sh en ERROR: ORA-01031:
>   insufficient privileges
>
> SP2-0306: Invalid option. Usage: CONN[ECT] [logon] [AS
>   {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM}] where   ::=
>   [/][@] [edition=value] | /
>   SP2-0306: Invalid option. Usage: CONN[ECT] [logon] [AS
>   {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM}] where   ::=
>   [/][@] [edition=value] | /
>   SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting
>   SQL*Plus [root@vEMS-23 devel]#

As far as I may understand it fails to authenticate as 'sysdba'. It doesn't occurs if I eliminate 'su - oracle -c' and run script as an oracle user initially.

Any clues?

---

**I've got an answer:**

The answer is pretty simple. I just a bit messed with syntax. The following is the working piece of code:

```
su - oracle -c 'sqlplus -s / as sysdba <<EOF
   whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
   set echo off 
   set heading off

   shutdown immediate
   startup mount
   alter database noarchivelog;
   alter database open;

   exit;
EOF
'
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

CONNECT chan/testing
SELECT *
FROM student;
EXIT;

save as /shell_with_oracledb_test/r_connection2.sql

write shell file as
echo "sqlplus /nolog @/shell_with_oracledb_test/r_connection2.sql" | su - oracle

name this file -> filename.sh

excute filename.sh file

This is sample code.